# grammar in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm displaying a string like "I'm an Actor" or "I'm a skateboarder" and need to use a or an correctly.

Is there a nifty rails view helper to see if a word starts with a vowel?

```
<p>I'm an <%= @user.skills %></p>

<p>I'm a <%= @user.skills %></p>
```

Comment: It's not just vowels, it's *vowel sounds*. An (<- unintentional) example: "I waited an hour for them.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It never got into rails: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2566-add-aan-inflector-indefinitize